# How to change/reset password for database in openshift

Tags: postgresql, configuration, openshift

When adding a database (postgresql) to my application in openshift the username and password is generated automatically. Is it possible to regenerate this password or to set it to a username/password of my choice?

Comment: In Postgres this would be `alter user ... pasword ...`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alteruser.html

Comment: Will this also change the environment variables in OpenShift? (not sure how the OpenShift database environment is set up, how much of  the configuration is automatized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenShift recommends that you do not change the default passwords that are setup for your database access.  Changing them can cause issues with maintenance that needs to be done on your application/database from time to time.  Also, the environment variables are not updated when you change your password (and I'm not sure that you can override them and set them yourself manually), you will have to use hard-coded values in your code.  It is up to you whether or not you change them, but again, it is not recommended.